# Python Delete Request for a rest api (on gae)

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, web-applications, spotify

After searching for a while, I found the following solutions for an api call that requires the Delete method.

First try: (httplib library)

```
    url = '/v1/users/'+ spotify_user_id +'/playlists/'+ playlist_id +'/tracks'
    data = json.dumps({"tracks": [{ "uri" : track_uri }]})
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        } 

    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.spotify.com')
    conn.request('DELETE', url , data, headers) 
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    content = resp.read()
    return json.loads(content)
```

This returns:

> {u'error': {u'status': 400, u'message': u'Empty JSON body.'}}

Second try:(urllib2 library)

```
    url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/'+ spotify_user_id +'/playlists/'+ playlist_id +'/tracks'
    data = json.dumps({"tracks": [{ "uri" : track_uri }]})
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        } 

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    req.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'

    try:
        response = opener.open(req).read()
        return response
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        return e
```

This returns:

> HTTP 400 Bad Request

I have other functions where the JSON is working, so I guess the problem is with the DELETE method but I can't get it working.

Besides this, the webapp is running on google app engine so i can't install packets so I would like to remain in the pre-installed librarys.
Anyone has a good way to do a Delete request on GAE? (I need to send both data and headers)

The API is spotify: developer.spotify.com/web-api/ and I'm trying to delete a track from a playlist.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting effort into asking your question. You've renewed my faith in SO, at least for a day.

Comment: Your second example looks odd
Have you considered just trying urlfetch - it supports the DELETE method.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction

Comment: I've tried to use to urlfetch and I get this response: {u'error': {u'status': 400, u'message': u'Empty JSON body.'}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found out it is impossible.

As stated at [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) (thanks to [@lukasa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401686/lukasa) for pointing out that RFC 2616 is obsolete), regarding the DELETE method :

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server remove the
> association between the target resource and its current
> functionality.  **In effect, this method is similar to the rm command**
> in UNIX: it expresses a deletion operation on the URI mapping of the
> origin server rather than an expectation that the previously
> associated information be deleted.

That said, deleting a track shouldn't need the track_uri to be passed in the body, but it should be in the URI.

Also, in the RFC:

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Google App Engine is one of this cases, not allowing a DELETE request to have a body.

That said the response from Spotify makes all the sense:

> Empty JSON body.

The best way to URL fetch in google apps is probably [their API for it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction) and I'm using it know for the rest of the requests.(For the ones who are using GAE and struggling between httplib, urllib2 and others).

The post I used for reference was [this one](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=601&q=post%20delete&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component).

I've asked Spotify if there is an alternative and the response from them was to Removed my Comment on Disqus!!

Comment: An update on this. [RFC 7231 Section 4.3.5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5), which supersedes your link to RFC 2616, says that "A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request." This is not the same as saying that a payload on DELETE is forbidden: it's entirely allowed. However, it means that using one is tricky and best avoided.

Comment: While we're here, it might be helpful to note that all of the Python HTTP libraries allow you to send a body when you're not using GAE: only on GAE do they forbid it.

Comment: Thanks @Lukasa, I've edited my answer with the new RFC. The answer remains the same because Spotify removed my comment on Disqus